# AutoComplete with Key-Value in grid, showing key when focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, grid, key-value

I am using paramquery grid component in which  I am trying to use autocomplete.

Column Model for branch:

```
{ title: "Branch", dataIndx: "branchId", width: 150,
                      filter: { type: "select",
                            condition: 'equal',
                            prepend: { '': '--All--' },
                            listeners: ['change'],
                            valueIndx: "branchId",
                            labelIndx: "branchName",
                            options: branchList,
                      },
                      editor: {
                          type: "textbox",
                          init: autoCompleteEditor
                          //type: function (ui) { return dropdowneditor(this, ui); }
                      },
                        render: function (ui) {

                           for (var i = 0; i < branchList.length; i++) {
                               var option = branchList[i];
                               if (option.branchId == ui.rowData.branchId) {
                                   return option.branchName;
                               } 
                           }
                      }
}
```

**autoCompleteEditorMethod**:

```
var autoCompleteEditor = function (ui) {
        var $inp = ui.$cell.find("input");

        //initialize the editor
        $inp.autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                var rows = imAutocompleteJSONParse(branchList);// this method converting my JSON object into Value and label format.
                return response(rows);
            },
            selectItem: { on: true }, //custom option
            highlightText: { on: true }, //custom option
            minLength: 0,
            select: function(event, ui) { 
                event.preventDefault();
                 $(this).val(ui.item.label);
            },
            focus: function(event, ui) { 
               event.preventDefault(); 
               $("#search").val(ui.item.label);
            }
        }).focus(function () {
            //open the autocomplete upon focus 

            $(this).autocomplete("search", "");
        });
    }
```

I get branch id into my grid and I have `branchList` JSON which have branch id & branch Name. Inside grid my render function showing `branchName` on UI.
But when I click on searchable dropdown I'm getting branch id.

Below snapshot may explain my issue properly.

[image]

Summary of issue: I am getting branch id in Grid. With help of render method I am able to show branch name on grid. but when I click on textbox I getting branch id.

http://jsfiddle.net/v4zx8tjc/4/

Comment: It would be better if you post a live demo.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/v4zx8tjc/4/

Answer (score 0):

Like [blackmiaool](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4831179/blackmiaool) suggests in his comment, this question would be easier to answer with a live demo using something like [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/).

Based on what I can see in your question, which isn't that much, there are a few areas I would take a second look at.

1. The Source function in JQuery.autoComplete. Where is `branchList` coming from? I don't see it declared anywhere and why are you not using the 'request' param?
2. Not sure what your custom properties are doing but it might be a good idea to verify those are not interfering with the results.

**Edit 1:** Looking back at the code you posted I think I see where your branchList variable is coming from. It would be very helpful to see your `imAutocompleteJSONParse()` method because I believe that may be where things are breaking down.